# chaining responses with axios and Vue js

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to chain three requests in one with Axios. I am practicing vue.js so please correct me if my approach is not ideal.

The goal is to have three requests. One is a post followed by 2 Gets. What I would like to achieve is one chained request.

My questions are:

1. Is this a good way to handle this? Should they be chained together like this?
2. Is it possible to map the response to a model like I did in the first post request and pass it to the next?

   ```
    const apiClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '08f852e........22fb3e2dc0...',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com'
    },
    params: {base64_encoded: 'true', fields: '*'},
   });

   export const api = {

    async submitCode(code: Code) {
        code.language_id = 60
        code.stdin = "Sn..2Uw"
        code.source_code = btoa(code.source_code)
        apiClient.post<Token>(`https://judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com/submissions?language_id=${code.language_id}&source_code=${code.source_code}&stdin=SnVkZ2Uw`)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("res.data", response.data.token);
        }).then(function (token) {
            console.log("token", token); // <---- empty
            `https://judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com/submissions/${token}`  // <---- get request
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log("res.data", response);
        }).then(function (response  ) {
            // here I will need a model
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            const error = err.response ? err.response.data : err;
            console.log("error" + error);
        })
    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to await each function if the next one is dependent on the previous. Or you could use Promise chaining in the traditional sense using `new Promise(resolve, reject)`. Async only applies to top level, so you will need to declare subsequent functions 'async' again as shown.

I would also suggest setting axios defaults with a base URL so you don't have to repeat the full URL each time. Note that `console.log` statements are not "Thenable" so your 1st statement has no effect, nor does your 3rd, other than to define your next variable.

```
const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com/submissons',
  // ... headers ... //
});

export const api = {
  async submitCode(code){
  // ... code variable ...//
  await apiClient.post(
    `?language_id=${code.language_id}&source_code=${code.source_code}&stdin=SnVkZ2Uw`)
    .then(async (response1) => {
      const token = response1.data.token
      await api.get(`/${token}`)
    }).then(async (response2) => {
      console.log(response2.data)
      const model = response2.data.map((val1) => apiClient.get(`anotherGet/${val1.id}`))
      const result = await Promise.all(model)
      return result.map((val2) => val2.data)
    })
  // ... catch ...//
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use`async`, then don't chain promices

```
async function submitCode(code: Code) {
    code.language_id = 60
    code.stdin = "Sn..2Uw"
    code.source_code = btoa(code.source_code)

    try { // ~ global `.catch`
        const token = await apiClient.post<Token>(`https://blah`)
        const get1result = await apiClient.get<Blah>(`https://balah?${token}`)
        const get2result = await apiClient.get<Blah>(`https://balah?${token}`)

        doBlah({token, get1result, get2result})
    } catch (err) { // maybe should check object type here
        const error = err.response ? err.response.data : err;
        console.log("error" + error);
    }
}
```

---

As for Vue, I can only recomment to use `asyncComputed` which you can feet Promise into if you need that

---

Express also had `express.api` or something with which you can skip `https://blah/com/api/` part of url, check it